# How many optimal alignments can be there for a string of length m with a string of length n?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, subsequences

So I was practicing optimal alignment algorithm and I was stuck with this question of finding optimal alignment for a string of length m with a string length n ? Also is it possible to run it in theta(n) times. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You are asking two questions. The usual rule is one question per post. Regarding your first question, consider what happens when all letters of both strings are the same.

Comment: Please formally define your question.